# CORS issue in Angular Application

Tags: php, angular, laravel, cors, angular6

I am working on Ajax call in Angular application and gettinng **CORS ISSUE**

1. getting  **CORS ISSUE** on sending correct data to the server . 
   **eg: {userName : 'Anurag'}**
2. not getting CORS Issue **but getting result[status] == 0** , on sending
   wrong data to the server eg: 'Anurag'
3. also **not getting any Issue in get methord Api** Interaction to the server , **I am only facing issue in post methord**

> How it is possible that **for POST** methord Api Interaction with server ,
>   **on sending correct data**  ,  I am **getting CORS issue** , and **for sending
>   wrong data** , I am **not getting CORS issue but error message with
>   result[Status] == 0**

technology details :

- FrontEnd : **Angular**
- Backend : **PHP(Laravel Framework)**

I am sharing my Angular code below :

**component.ts file**

```
   checkusername(value){
     this.res.usernameCheck({"username": this.userSignup.value.username}).subscribe(result => {
          console.log(result);
        })
      }
```

**service file**

```
usernameCheck(data) : Observable<any>{
     console.log(data);
     return this.http.post(this.checkuserName , data);
   }
```

while calling http request **I am getting below given error**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://www.XXXXXXXXX.com/crmApi/public/api/userNameCheck'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Request header field content-type is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
>
> core.js:9110 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0,
>   statusText: "Unknown Error", url:
>   "https://XXXXXXXXX.com/crmApi/public/api/userNameCheck",
>   ok: false, …}

To Fix this issue , I have put below code  in controller page but still I am getting same error

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

I am sharing my backend PHP code below

**controller.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\login;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\loginModel\signupModel;

class signupController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        // header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate');
        // header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type' );
    }
    public function countryCode()
    {
        $signupModel = new signupModel();
        $data = $signupModel->countryCode();
        // header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        return response()->json($data);
    }
    public function jobTitle()
    {
        // $headers = $header = request()->headers->all();
        // print_r($headers);exit();
        $signupModel = new signupModel();
        $data = $signupModel->jobTitle();
        // header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        return response()->json($data);
    }
    public function userNameCheck(Request $request)
    {
        $username=$request->json()->get('username');
        // print_r($username);exit();
        // header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        // header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        // header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
        if($username == '')
            return response()->json(["status"=>"0","message"=>"Please provide username"]);
        else
        {
            $signupModel = new signupModel();
            $data = $signupModel->userNameCheck($username);
            // print_r($data);exit();
            if($data)
                return response()->json(["status"=>"1","message"=>"username exist"]);
            else
                return response()->json(["status"=>"0","message"=>"username does not exist"]);
        }
    }
    public function signUp(Request $request)
    {
        $name=$request->json()->get('name');
        $username=$request->json()->get('username');
        $password=$request->json()->get('password');
        $job_title=$request->json()->get('job_title');
        $job_role=$request->json()->get('job_role');
        $email=$request->json()->get('email');
        $country_code=$request->json()->get('country_code');
        $phone_number=$request->json()->get('phone_number');
        $addstr1=$request->json()->get('addstr1');
        $country=$request->json()->get('country');
        $state=$request->json()->get('state');
        $city=$request->json()->get('city');
        $postal_code=$request->json()->get('postal_code');
        $tokenData=md5(date('ymdhisa')).$username.$email;
        $token = hash_hmac('sha256',$tokenData,true);
        $token = base64_encode($token);
        // print_r($token);exit();
        // header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        if($name == '')
            return response()->json(["status"=>"0","message"=>"Please provide name"]);
        elseif($username == '')
            return response()->json(["status"=>"0","message"=>"Please provide username"]);
        elseif($password == '')
            return response()->json(["status"=>"0","message"=>"Please provide password"]);
        elseif($job_title == '')
            return response()->json(["status"=>"0","message"=>"Please provide job title"]);
        elseif($job_role == '')
            return response()->json(["status"=>"0","message"=>"Please provide job role"]);
        elseif($email == '')
            return response()->json(["status"=>"0","message"=>"Please provide email"]);
        elseif($country_code == '')
            return response()->json(["status"=>"0","message"=>"Please provide country code"]);
        elseif($phone_number == '')
            return response()->json(["status"=>"0","message"=>"Please provide phone number"]);
        else
        {
            $signupModel = new signupModel();
            $userCheck = $signupModel->userNameCheck($username);
            // print_r($userCheck);exit();
            if($userCheck)
            {
                return response()->json(["status"=>"0","message"=>"User exist"]);
            }
            else
            {
                $data = $signupModel->signUp($name,$username,$password,$job_title,$job_role,$email,$country_code,$phone_number,$addstr1,$country,$state,$city,$postal_code,$token);
                return response()->json($data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I built something similar: [laravel cors middleware](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

And I have add every request in angular the following:

```
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            // 'Authorization': ''
        }
    ),
```

Comment: This "answer" should have been a comment.

Comment: And Mohamed's answer as well

Answer (score 0):

First check your response header (chrome console).[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKTiF.jpg)

But it's better to use a middleware cors  to specify header response as below :

https://gist.github.com/DavidCWebs/4e4adde53a9c54f94e25e8a72f1251e8

Mohamed.

Comment: This "answer" should have been a comment. See [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/386424)

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

Navigate through this path on a console in your system   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>`

Then enter below command `chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security --user-data-dir --disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating`

This works for me.

Comment: After opening chrome in this way, then run your project.

Answer (score -1):

Don't add random code to the Laravel framework, just install a library that does the job. In your case it can be tymon/jwt. Install the appropriate version that is compatible with your Laravel version. This library give you the flexibility to apply CORS to all routes or you can choose the ones you want. Also your choice of adding headers to a controllers is a bad one, you are better off using a middleware to do so.